# Generating DataFrame from Multiplication Table Printout - Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

In my following code, I am producing print-outs of randomly generated multiplication tables. I would like to make each table generated into a DataFrame. How would I do this? (New in Python 3.x)

This exercise was to generate a multiplication table. It expanded to a project to generate a set number of
multiplication tables with randomly generated one- or two-digit column and row numbers. Currently it is set to run five tables, each with 8 columns and rows. However, these numbers can be changed. Jupyter Notebook can
only print up to 12 columns nicely. While our program will generate as many columns and rows as we want (of equal size, eg, 6x6, 3x3, 9x9, etc), limiting it to a 12x12 matrix or smaller is best for viewing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

# This sets up how many tables we will generate
for t in range(0,5):

    # Make variable place holders for our columns and rows list
    a=[]
    b=[]

    # To use randomly generated numbers, this sets up the random column numbers 'a' and random row numbers 'b'
    import random
    for x in range(12):
        a.append(random.randint(41,99)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of numbers here
        b.append(random.randint(1,35)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of number here


    # Add the column titles for each table - these are the random numbers 'a'
    print("C/R: ", end="\t ")
    for number in a:
        print(number,end = '\t ')
    print()

    # The double for-loop to generate the table
    for row in b:
        print(row, end="\t") # First column
        for number in a:
            print(round(row*number,1),end='\t' )# Next columns
        print( )

    # Add two blank cosmetic lines between tables for readability
    print('\n\n')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon Josewails' assistance, this is the code for which I was looking. Josewails, thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

# This sets up how many tables we will generate
for t in range(0,5):

    # Make variable place holders for our columns and rows list
    a = []
    b = []
    dataframes = []

    # To use randomly generated numbers, this sets up the random column numbers 'a' and random row numbers 'b'
    import random
    for x in range(12):
        a.append(random.randint(41,99)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of numbers here
        b.append(random.randint(1,35)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of number here

    data = []

    for row in b:
        temp = []
    for number in a:
        temp.append(round(row*number,1))

    data.append(temp)

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=a)
    dataframe.index = b

    dataframes.append(dataframe)

    display(dataframes[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring your code a bit should give the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

# This sets up how many tables we will generate

dataframes = []

for t in range(0,5):

    # Make variable place holders for our columns and rows list
    a = []
    b = []

    # To use randomly generated numbers, this sets up the random column numbers 'a' and random row numbers 'b'
    import random
    for x in range(12):
        a.append(random.randint(41,99)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of numbers here
        b.append(random.randint(1,35)) # We can adjust the range of the random selection of number here

    data = []

    for row in b:
        temp = []
        for number in a:
            temp.append(round(row*number,1))

        data.append(temp)

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=a)
    dataframe.index = b

    dataframes.append(dataframe)

dataframes[0]
```

This is the output.

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGHX.png)

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what the last line `dataframes[0]` does.

Comment: `dataframaes[0]` is meant to display the first object of the list `dataframes`.